# How do I load IQFeed data in Julia

Tags: julia, quantitative-finance

In Julia, how do I load IQFeed data at high speed?
We purchased a license for IQFeed

I want to do something like this [import, and cleanup (removing NA's or otherwise treating missing data)]
(https://grollchristian.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/sp500-data-download-julia/)

He uses [EconDatasets](https://github.com/JuliaFinMetriX/EconDatasets.jl) I did not understand which feed it takes from?

Or perhaps I have to modify the [bloomberg.jl](https://github.com/milktrader/Bloomberg.jl) package?

Or perhaps reading from the IQFeed is something totally different?

I could not find any documentation on how to do this. I'm new to Julia, and to using IQFeed.

I saw a list of ['qunatitative financial computing' packages](https://github.com/JuliaQuant) but none seem to address the import of technical financing data and analysis of that imported data.

I saw [pyiqfeed for importing iqfeed in Python](https://github.com/akapur/pyiqfeed/blob/master/launch_iqfeed.py) that uses sockets.

```
# Modify code below to connect to the socket etc as described above
admin = iq.AdminConn(name="Launcher")
admin_listener = iq.VerboseAdminListener("Launcher-listen")
admin.add_listener(admin_listener)
with iq.ConnConnector([admin]) as connected:
    admin.client_stats_on()
    while not os.path.isfile(ctrl_file):
        time.sleep(10)

os.remove(ctrl_file)
```

I also read about [Julia accessing a csv from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229984/reading-data-from-url), but it seems this is not the case. I'll need to run the supplied software and then...?

Anyone have experience with Julia and IQFeed or similar? (Are there any julia programmers around today at all)?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you get a response to this for now. There are plenty of people working hard with julia (some, like myself, are from a quant finance background). But the language is still in beta. The problems that are currently being worked on by the community are much more general than interfacing with specific suppliers, e.g. standardizing dataframes, fast csv parsing, e.t.c.. If you wanted to work on an interface for iqfeed yourself, you would get plenty of support from the community, but AFAIK there is no package that is ready-to-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Colin T. Bowers, Julia is still in beta, and there are no packages for it. For this reason we decided not to go on with Julia.

So the short answer is: There is none.

If you still want to go at it yourself, The easiest way to go would be to use one of the two available open source python IQFeed packages, which basically call sockets with a predefined text (utf-8) message and receive a result in a callback.

Turning them into Julia seems to me to be quite easy.

You'll need to run the IQFeed client first with a username/pw you get from them.